# Magic square with not consecutive numbers

Tags: magic-square

A magic square should be filled with the following numbers: 7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,17. The numbers: 15, 16 and 17 are already placed as the following:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    &17\\  \hline
15&&\\  
   \hline
&&16\\  \hline\end{array}$$

Which algorithm should be used to fill such that magic square?

Comment: First. figure out what constant must be the sum of the various lines.

Comment: Sum of all numbers =? Size of magic square =? Hence sum of one row/column =?

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried the first two hints?  They should take you far.

Comment: They didn't provide the magic constant. @RossMillikan

Comment: But if you add up all three lines, you add up all the numbers.  The magic constant is then one third of that.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain more please? @Ross Millikan

Comment: How each line (row/column) sum is equal the magic constant then the sum of all three lines (three rows/ three column) results in 3 times the magic constant. Besides this the central element is equal the magic constant ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given that all the rows sum to the same number.  If you add up all the numbers in the three rows, you get all the numbers in the matrix.  The sum is $7+8+9+11+12+13+15+16+17=108$.  The magic constant must then be $\frac {108}3=36$.

To make a sum of $36$ with $17$ included, the only possibilities are $7+12+17$ and $8+11+17$, so either the top row is $8,11,17$ in some order and the center column is $7,12,17$ in some order, or they are reversed.

To make a sum of $36$ with $15$ included, the only possibilities are $9+12+15$ and $8+13+15$.  The upper left and center squares must be $8$ and $12$ because these are the only numbers common to the sums for $15$ and $17$.

If we make the upper left $12$, the center is $8$ , the middle in the right column is $13$, the top right is $7$ from the rows, and the right column fails.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
   12 &17&7\\  \hline
15&8&13\\  
   \hline
&&16\\  \hline\end{array}$$so the upper left must be $8$ and the center $12$.  From there it is easy to fill in the rest.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    8&17&11\\  \hline
15&12&9\\  
   \hline
13&7&16\\  \hline\end{array}$$

Comment: In your trial with 8 is the center the right column is actually good.  The failure comes when you try to place a number in the lower left corner.  The column requires 9 but the diagonal requires 21, which is inconsistent both internally and with the given number list.

Comment: @OscarLanzi:  are you commenting on the failed first square?  It is the argument that places $8$ and $12$ in position.  There are many ways to see the contradiction.  The final square is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rule is that in a 3×3 magic square the center element must be the average of all of the numbers, and then the sum of any three elements in a row, column or diagonal is three times this average.

Here you can show that the average of all nine elements is $12$, which therefore has to occupy the center, and then the magic sum has to be $3×12=36$.

After this it's all simple arithmetic.